# How to collect all routing of my symfony project to create sitemap?

Tags: php, xml, symfony, routes, sitemap

Now I use the bellow tutorial to create sitemap.xml of my project.

[Xml sitemaps with Symfony2](http://enarion.net/programming/php/symfony2/xml-sitemaps/)

To add URI (routes) of my project I should add them one bye one.

The question is:

"How to use symfony routing system to get all routing of symfony?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the job:

```
$routes = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getRouteCollection();

foreach ($routes as $route) {
    // add to sitemap
}
```

This is the API info:

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html#method_getRouteCollection